# It's possible to import and use Zbrush sculpt brushes into Blender?

Tags: add-on, sculpting, zbrush

I was searching for good textures and brushes and i found that there's a pack of brushes of a worker of Blizzard that can be used in Blender, the ORB's textures brushes.

https://www.blendernation.com/2017/08/24/free-download-orbs-sculpt-brushes/

So, the thing is that there are a lot of textures out there exclusively for Zbrush instead of Blender, so, is there a way to use these Zbrush sculpt brushes in Blender?

..Or there's an addon that can enable that?

Comment: Are you just talking about the Alpha Textures that are used in ZBrush, or the actual brush settings? The Alpha Textures/Images can be used as Brush Textures in Blender, though the brush settings need to be set up manually.

Comment: I was talking about the alpha textures. Thanks for solving this doubt :)

Comment: The zbrush website has a lot of alpha textures which you can download for free. Though there are specific brushes in zbrush which cannot be duplicated in blender.

Answer (score 1):

A person did this with the same pack you are talking about
http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/86419
Here's the link